# How to change default Div position in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am working with bootstrap and I would like to change default div positions when screen changes to small screen. Basically bootstrap div positions like this.

[image]

But I want divs like this.

[image]

I have tried pull and push method. But it doesn't work.

Thanks.

```html
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <img src="http://loremflickr.com/320/240" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h4>
      New here!
    </h4>
    <p>
      LoremFlickr is a service that provides free placeholder images for web and print. ... Photos come from Flickr and have a Creative Commons license. ...
    </p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
 
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h4>
      New here!
    </h4>
    <p>
      LoremFlickr is a service that provides free placeholder images for web and print. ... Photos come from Flickr and have a Creative Commons license. ...
    </p>
  </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <img src="http://loremflickr.com/320/240" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap? v3.3.7 or v4? Which grid?

Comment: @FelipeAls, Bootstrap v3.3.7

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap works from small to big, check the [Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid) documention. So in your case, if you want to set all the divs at full width, use the `col-xs-12` class everywhere:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
       ...image
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
       second row
    </div>
</div>
...etc
```

Comment: Just look at my code and look at my image. I want image first, text below in mobile screens.

Answer (score 0):

(see below for my edit. First the CSS way, then the BS4 way)

If you're using v4 beta and its flexbox grid, you can use order property in a MQ to rearrange the items of the BootStrap grid.

- (negative including) `-1` value: will display before others (from the most negative to -1 and for identical values in the order of appearance in markup
- `0` (which is the default): no rearrangement
- (positive including) `1`: will display after others (from 1 to the most positive and for identical values in the order of appearance in markup

Bootply with v4 beta: https://www.bootply.com/U4Koah4OcO

In markup, I rearranged items in the order you want in XS and via a MQ for *small and up* rearranged image to display after all other. If you don't want to modify your markup then you can set `order: 1` on the last paragraph and override it to `0` in *small and up* resolutions.

**EDIT:** The BootStrap v4 way of **reordering** is using `.order-N` classes. [Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#reordering)

```css
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .not-here-but-there {
    order: 1;
    outline: 3px dashed blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- With BS v4 beta - 
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <img src="http://loremflickr.com/320/240" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h4>
          New here!
        </h4>
        <p>
          LoremFlickr is a service that provides free placeholder images for web and print. ... Photos come from Flickr and have a Creative Commons license. ...
        </p>
      </div>
    
      <div class="col-sm-6 not-here-but-there">
        <img src="http://loremflickr.com/320/240" />
      </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h4>
          New here!
        </h4>
        <p>
          LoremFlickr is a service that provides free placeholder images for web and print. ... Photos come from Flickr and have a Creative Commons license. ...
        </p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am using bootstrap 3 only. How to do with BS3

Answer (score 0):

@Melbin Mathai Please check following code, in which I have added bootstrap classes for different screens. I hope you were expecting the same.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
      <img src="http://loremflickr.com/320/240" />
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
      <h4>
         New here!
      </h4>
      <p>
         LoremFlickr is a service that provides free placeholder images for web and print. ... Photos come from Flickr and have a Creative Commons license. ...
      </p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <h4>
         New here!
      </h4>
      <p>
         LoremFlickr is a service that provides free placeholder images for web and print. ... Photos come from Flickr and have a Creative Commons license. ...
      </p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
      <img src="http://loremflickr.com/320/240" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But Just take a look at the image in the question. Your answer is same as first image. I want it looks like exact same as second image.

Comment: @Melbin Mathai Ok, got it. I just edited my code. Please have a look again.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this     
<div class="container">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                 <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" />
             </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        <h4>
          New here!
        </h4>
        <p>
          LoremFlickr is a service that provides free placeholder images for web and print. ... Photos come from Flickr and have a Creative Commons license. ...
        </p>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
     <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-md-push-6" >
       <img src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">
        <h4>
          New here!
        </h4>
        <p>
          LoremFlickr is a service that provides free placeholder images for web and print. ... Photos come from Flickr and have a Creative Commons license. ...
        </p>
      </div>

    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```